# replace div value with .txt

Tags: ajax

I am trying to replace the value of data in span

```
.ajax ({
.
.
.
success: function(data){
                $("#ID1").html(data[0]);
                $("#ID2").val(data[1]);
                }
            });
<span id ='ID1'>test</span>
<input id = 'ID2'>
```

return data is [["abc"],["def"]] using json_encode
ID1 is not changing test to abc while
value of ID2 is able to change to def
what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$("#ID1").html(data[0])` instead of  `$("#ID1").val(data[0]);`

Comment: It works if I fix the value $("#ID1").html("abc"); but this is not what I am looking at

Comment: if it works for hardcoded string, then probably need to look for ajax response.

Comment: see if you are getting the correct ajax response you are expecting.

Comment: OK change my original code. If the ajax respond does not work, the value for input shall not have change but for my case, it change using $("#ID2").val(data[1]); . span doesn't chaneg